# Restore data in tab view after tab change

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

I have an Android application where I need to switch between two tabs. I am using Fragments. The problem is that when I type something in an editText box on one tab and switch to another tab, the original one gets reset to the default values.

Based on the answers I found on different forums, I am saving the state:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, show the tab contents in the
    // container view.
    Fragment fragment = new TabsSectionFragment();
    //fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(TabsSectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER,
            tab.getPosition() + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}
```

In the onCreateView, I am loading a couple of layouts:

```
public static class TabsSectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public TabsSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int selectedSection = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        switch (selectedSection)
        {
            case 1:
                // load the input layout XML
                LayoutInflater factory1 = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                View myView1 = factory1.inflate(R.layout.tab1, null);
                return myView1;

            case 2:
                // load the summary layout XML
                LayoutInflater factory2 = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                View myView2 = factory2.inflate(R.layout.tab2, null);
                return myView2;

            default:
                // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
                // number argument value.
                TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                        ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

                return textView;
        }
    }
}
```

How should I use the savedInstanceState to restore the tab state so I do not lose the info I typed before switching the tab.

I have also read that some people recommend hiding and showing the fragment instead of saving/reloading states. What's a better option.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I would change your approach and use tabhost

```
 private TabHost tabhost;
 private View view1;
 private View view2;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.mainLayout);
   tabhost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhostView);
     tabhost.setup();
     tabhost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);
     view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view1,    null);
     view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view2, null);
     setupTab(view1, "View1");
     setupTab(view2, "View2");
 //set tab
 tabhost.setCurrentTab(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(CURRENT_TAB));
 }
```

Then create 2 methods to set each view like:

```
  private void buildView1(View view) {
  <enter code here>
   view.invalidate
}
```